# Search for multiple keywords and corresponding index

Tags: python-3.x, substring

I have strings like:

```
a = "currency is like gbp"

a= "currency blah blah euro"

a= "currency is equivalent to usd" .....
```

I want to substring or slice the above string wherever I found any of "gbp" , "euro" or  "usd".

**Not Working:**

```
i = a.find("gbp") or a.find("euro") or a.find("usd")
a = a[i:]
```

**Can do:**

```
x = a.find('gbp')
y = a.find('euro')
z = a.find('usd')
```

But then I need to check which of them is greater than -1 and use that variable to slice the string which will be too much code.

Also, in  my original example I have 10+ currencies so want a scalable solution.

**Summary:**

Want to slice/substring the main sentence from any of the words found till the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
currency_array = ['gbp', 'euro', 'usd']

index = max(a.find(currency) for currency in currency_array)

print(a[index:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex for such purposes:

```
import re

a = "currency is like gbp currency"
print(re.findall(r'((?:gbp|euro|usd).*)', a))

# ['gbp currency']
```